# Convert Set of POJOs to JSON returns only "id" fields

Tags: java, json, jersey-2.0, moxy

I have a peculiar issue in my project. I have bootstrapped a REST endpoint from a mvn archetype basing on Jersey+Grizzly2+Moxy.
This endpoint returns a **Set** of all POJOs in the DataSource. So what happens is that when I *@GET* the endpoint it returns this:

```
[{"id":1},{"id":0}]
```

for 2 objects in the DataSource. If I **println** these objects I get:

```
[[1 username1 fullName1 ROLE_USR], [0 username2 fullName2 ROLE_USR]]
```

What's the deal here? Why isn't it serializing all the fields but shows only the **id** field?

**EDIT 1:**
Adding my POJO definition:

```
public class User  {

    private int id;
    private final String emailAddress;
    private final String username;
    private String password;
    private String displayName;
    private String description;
    private USER_ROLE role;

    // Constructors, setters & getters

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "[" + id + " " +
                username + " " +
                displayName + " " +
                role + "]";
    }
}
```

Comment: please share pojo class also

Comment: added to original question.. Now that I think of it - maybe it's because the fields are private? Could that be the case? But then how can it pull 'id' out if i'ts private too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed issue by switching back to Jackson. Seems MOXy is not fulfilling it's job as the recommended JSON library. replacing

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId>
    <version>${jersey.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

with

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
    <version>${jersey.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

did the trick and now my endpoint returns expected values.